# Typescript: function return object type with field from parameter

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I need to define the result of the function as object with field names from parameters. Somthing like this:

```
function generate<R>(name: string, value: () => R): { [name]: R } {
    return {
        [name]: value()
    };
}
const s = generate('foo', () => 1);
assert(s.foo === 1);
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve it with some help of overloadings:

```js
function generate<T extends string, R>(name: T, value: () => R): Record<T, R>
function generate<T extends string, R>(name: T, value: () => R) {
  return {
    [name]: value()
  }
}
const s = generate('foo', () => 1); // ecord<"foo", number>
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAcwKZlQJwIZVQHgBVFUAPPMAEwGdFqpMYxkAaRAJQD4AKMbAW1QAuRITYA3bABsQwxNwCUiALycOCke1QQ4mSkTZcAsAChQkWAhTosuAsTIUadBk1YcefQSLGJJMuUUVNXYlAG9TRERMVCgQTCQIkyiogG0vVABdEX9ZRUjEAF9TYpMdMHo6FWsMHDxuAHJgODgGtiDVRABGBQBuRAB6AZIdPXwAIma4cbYwEH4AIyxOU1MgA)